# Load stage with all elements in kineticjs

Tags: javascript, json, kineticjs

I try load my simple stage from json file, I load images but it's all in one layer, and image is not in group, so resize not working, i don't know how i should to load all elements with layers and group;

This is my function to load(it's only image for now)

```
   function load(loadStage) {
    counter = 2;
    activeStage = stage;
    stage = Kinetic.Node.create(loadStage,'right');
    var background = stage.get('.background');
    var backgroundImage = stage.get('.backgroundImage');
    var clipartsImage = stage.get('.image');
    var text = stage.get('.text');
    console.log(stage.getChildren());


   for(i=0;i<clipartsImage.length;i++){ 
     counter++;
      (function() { 

          var image = clipartsImage[i];
          groups[counter] = image.parent.get;
          //console.log(image);
          var imageObj = new Image();
          imageObj.onload = function() {
              imageObj.src = image.attrs.src;
              console.log(image);
              image.setImage(imageObj);

              image.on('mouseover', function() {
                  document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
              });
              image.on('mouseout', function() {
                  document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
              });

              image.on('click', function(evt) {
                  this.children[0].children[3].show();
                  var shape = evt.targetNode;
                  this.moveToTop();
                  active = layers[shape.getId()];
                  objectId = shape.getId();
              });
              image.getLayer().draw;
          };
          imageObj.src = image.attrs.src;
      })();

      stage.draw();
    }
    stage.draw();
}
```

And this is my json file, http://wklej.org/id/1105520/ this is middle stage. I'll keep trying, but if someone has had a similar problem and solved it, I would be grateful for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

### 1)

What is going on with your JSON file? the base64 string has blown up into a million lines...

For starters, KineticJS.Layer **cannot** have a layer as a child. References:

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki/Change-Log#455-july-28-2013

> new add() validation. An error is thrown if invalid children are added to a parent, for example, when adding a layer to another layer.

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki

[KineticJS event not fired for child of a grouped layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453342/kineticjs-event-not-fired-for-child-of-a-grouped-layer/17453939#17453939)

Inside your JSON file, you have tons of layers layered within each other, this is **definitely** going to cause a problem. Actually it looks like you have a layer for EACH group that you have! This is completely wrong KineticJS structure.

You should do some research on how and when to use layers and groups, here are some references:

[What are the differences between group and layer in KineticJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632068/what-are-the-differences-between-group-and-layer-in-kineticjs/17632137)

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki (again, the data structure hierarchy for KineticJS)

### 2)

No need to call `stage.draw()` twice.

### 3)

JSON is a **data** format, it only stores object attributes. This means it **does not** store any references to events attached to objects.

What this means is that when you load your JSON string, you'll have to rebind the `updateAnchor` function to all your anchors again. (Similar to how you are rebinding `click` function to your images onload)

You'll have to do something like this inside your load function, after you create the stage with your JSON file:

```
var children = layer.getChildren(); //Use the layer that has all your groups with images/anchors. *REMEMBER you can't layers within layers!

for (var i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
  //If name starts with 'anchor'
  if (children.getName().indexOf('anchor') !== -1) {
    children[i].on('dragmove', function(evt) {
      updateAnchor(this);
      layer.draw();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for help, I rebuild my projects and after i try this solution :)